# python 3 programming lottery number generator

Tags: python-3.6, google-colaboratory

am writing a code which like the lottery should produce a list of 6 numbers like this (20,45,11,16,09, + 12)

#### numbers have to be from 1 to 50

How do I do it so that it just gives me the last line all 5 randomly chosen values plus the additional number all within one list:

```
import random 
a = list(range(1,50))

b = random.randint(1, 20)

temp = []


for i in range(5):

temp.append(random.choice(a))

print(temp, "+", b) code here


output:

[8] + 12

[8, 30] + 12

[8, 30, 42] + 12

[8, 30, 42, 21] + 12

**[8, 30, 42, 21, 14] + 12**
```

Comment: Before I can answer your question, I do have a few questions on my own:
 1. are the numbers randomly drawn without replacement?
 2. It seems that the drawn numbers and the additional number come from two different sets, is that correct?
 3. Is your desired result [N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, Additional]? I.e. is your question how to add a value to a list in python?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with how lottery works. I assume that all numbers, including the additional number, are drawn from the same set without replacement. If that is true, this code should do the trick for you:

```py
import random
numbers = list(range(1, 51)) # include 50
random.shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers[:6]) # pick the first 6 numbers (5 + 1 additional number) in the randomize list
```

---

If your additional number comes from a separate set, do this:

```py
import random
numbers = list(range(1, 51)) # include 50
random.shuffle(numbers)
# pick the first 5 from the randomized list:
picks = numbers[:5]
# select from remaining numbers those that are less than or equal to 20:
picks.append(random.choice([n for n in numbers[5:] if n <= 20]))
print(picks)
```

Comment: thank you but how do I make it so that the number from the additional list is never the same as the number form the first list eg:[11, 21, 18, 36, 10, 10]

Comment: Please accept my answer then (click the gray check mark to the left of my answer). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Expending on the previous answer based on your request to exclude previously picked numbers while generating the last number.

```
import random

numbers = list(range(1, 51)) # create a list containing 1 to 50
random.shuffle(numbers) # randomise the list

picks = numbers[:5] # pick the first 5 numbers from the randomised list

# select the last number from the remaining numbers in the list
picks.append(random.choice([n for n in numbers if n not in picks]))
print(picks)
```